# Why do I get this Windows Installer window every time I boot up my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm getting the following window every time Windows 10 boots up. I can close it and it doesn't pop up at any other time.

[image]

What does it mean, and what should I do to make it go away?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like Autoruns to determine what will run at startup: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

You will want to look for something that is either:

- An entry for a MSI file.
- Something that has arguments to run a MSI file.
- An entry for msiexec.exe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an app called "autoruns" to check which programs are executed when you boot your windows and look for "msiexec.exe" on that list if you want to remove it

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.